# Proving the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix is given by $2s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove:

> $$\begin{vmatrix}a^2&(s-a)^2&(s-a)^2\\(s-b)^2&b^2&(s-b)^2\\(s-c)^2&(s-c)^2&c^2\end{vmatrix}=2s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c),\;\;s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

My attempt:

Let $c_1,c_2,c_3$ be columns and $r_1,r_2,r_3$ be rows.

$c_3-c_2:$
$$\begin{vmatrix}a^2&(s-a)^2&0\\(s-b)^2&b^2&s(s-2b)\\(s-c)^2&(s-c)^2&-s(s-2c)\end{vmatrix}$$
$c_2-c_1:$
$$\begin{vmatrix}a^2&s(s-2a)&0\\(s-b)^2&-s(s-2b)&s(s-2b)\\(s-c)^2&0&-s(s-2c)\end{vmatrix}$$
$c_2\cdot\frac{1}{s},c_3\cdot\frac{1}{s}$
$$s^2\begin{vmatrix}a^2&(s-2a)&0\\(s-b)^2&-(s-2b)&(s-2b)\\(s-c)^2&0&-(s-2c)\end{vmatrix}$$

Then, by LaPLace on the $3^{\text{rd}}$ column, I got:
$$-(s-2b)(s-2a)(s-c)^2-(s-2c)\left(a^2(2b-s)-(s-2a)(s-b)^2\right)$$

Which got too complicated. May I ask how to end this task?

Comment: The determinant should be a polynomial of degree $6$, not $5$.

Comment: Up to a change of variables, it is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393454/computing-determinant-without-expansion

Comment: The identity is correct if the right hand side is $2s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$.

Comment: Why not just directly calculate the determinant by cofactors expansion?

Comment: I've edited your title so that it takes less space and has some text. I've also changed the $s^2$ into $s^3$ because that's what it *should* be, so I suspect the $s^2$ was a typo or something.

Comment: @Arnaud D., thank you for correction!

Comment: By setting $a=b+c$, $b=c+a$, or $c=a+b$, you get that the determinant is $0$.  Since the determinant is a polynomial in $a$, $b$, and $c$, this shows that $s-a=\frac{b+c-a}2$, $s-b=\frac{c+a-b}2$, and $s-c=\frac{a+b-c}2$ are factors of the determinant.  When $a+b+c=0$, the determinant is also $0$, so $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$ must also be a factor of the determinant.  Therefore you know that at least that $s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ is a factor.  Then by symmetry and homogeneity, you may assume that $\big(x(a^2+b^2+c^2)+y(bc+ca+ab)\big)s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ equals the determinant.  Solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMMENT.-Put $S_a=s-a$ and analogues you have
$$\begin{vmatrix}a^2&S_a^2&S_a^2\\S_b^2&b^2&S_b^2\\S_c^2&S_c^2&c^2\end{vmatrix}=2s^3S_aS_bS_c$$ By property of determinants one has
$$LHS=\begin{vmatrix}a^2&S_a^2&0\\S_b^2&b^2&S_b^2-b^2\\S_c^2&S_c^2&S_c-c^2\end{vmatrix}=2S_a^2S_b^2S_c^2-a^2S_b^2S_c^2-b^2S_a^2S_c^2-c^2S_a^2S_b^2$$ With this the verification of the identity is straightforward but tedious.

An easier way is to consider $a,b,c$ as the sides of a triangle so you have to prove
$$LHS=R^6\begin{vmatrix}4(\sin \alpha)^2&(-\sin \alpha+\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)^2&(-\sin \alpha+\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)^2\\(\sin \alpha-\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)^2&4(\sin \beta)^2&(\sin \alpha-\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)^2\\(\sin \alpha+\sin\beta-\sin \gamma)^2&(\sin \alpha+\sin\beta-\sin \gamma)^2&4(\sin \gamma)^2\end{vmatrix}$$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle.

You have for the $RHS$ $$s=R(\sin \alpha+\sin \beta+\sin \gamma)\\s-a=R(-\sin \alpha+\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)\\s-b=R(\sin \alpha-\sin\beta+\sin \gamma)\\s-c=R(\sin \alpha+\sin\beta-\sin \gamma)$$ This way is easier without doubt.