# Determinant Identity: Elegant Solution Please.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can anyone provide a proof of this identity:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 &a^2&a^2\\
b^2&(a+c)^2&b^2\\
c^2&c^2&(a+b)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}=2abc(a+b+c)^3 ?$$

Ideally I would like a series of row column operations resulting in the formula.
No brute force calculations. Note that letting $a=0$ we get two rows equal. So $abc$ is a factor. But I have unable to produce this by a simple series of operations, I mean to get one row or column all of whose entries are divisible by $a$. Getting divisibility by $(a+b+c)^2$ is also not hard just subtract one column from the other two. After that however I have been unable to make any further progress. Hopefully someone here is smarter than I.

Comment: Where is this identity from?

Comment: I find using the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) elegant enough, but I suppose this is not enough? I obtain $\det(A)=2abc(a+b+c)^3$.

Comment: I think you miss a power of $3$ on the right.

Comment: Opps, yeah I forgot the exponent, thanks.

Comment: @mrsamy Its from an old (like 19th century) algebra text.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: thanks. Do you have a name for the reference?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Any problem with my solution?

Comment: @mrsamy  Hall and Knight, Higher Algebra. You can find it on Internet Archive.

Comment: @Whyareyoureadingmyname What do you mean by open by last row ? I think you mean the expansion by cofactors, and this is somewhat contrary to the spirit of the question. Also there isnt anything so far that I havent arrived at myself. But I will up vote you.

Comment: See this analogous question: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2393454 obtained using https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Check the edit. It now should be within the spirit of the question I think,

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Do tell me if you still find something wrong with my solution. Your constructive criticism will help me.

Comment: If you have divisibility by  $a,b,c$ and by $(a+b+c)^2$, it has to be (up to a constant) $abc(a+b+c)^3$, because the polynomial has to be symmetric in $a,b,c$ and homogenous of degree $6$. I do wonder what the sensible abstract way of reasoning that the root $a+b+c$ has multiplicity $3$ is, though.

Comment: @JeanMarie Wow, its the exact same question.

Comment: @Thorgott Yes, I have wondered that also.

Comment: @Thorgott To complete the argument, note that the final factor is linear so we can write the result as $abc(a+b+c)^2 (ra+sb+tc)$ where $r,s,t$ are coefficients to be determined by setting $a=-1, b=c=1$ etc, or by symmetry say that $r=s=t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 &a^2&a^2\\
b^2&(a+c)^2&b^2\\
c^2&c^2&(a+b)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2-a^2 &0&a^2\\
0&(a+c)^2-b^2&b^2\\
c^2-(a+b)^2&c^2 - (a+b)^2&(a+b)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2-a^2 &0&a^2\\
0&(a+c)^2-b^2&b^2\\
c^2-(a+b^2)&c^2 - (a+b)^2&(a+b)^2\\
\end{vmatrix} =(a+b+c)^2\begin{vmatrix}
b+c-a &0&a^2\\
0&a+c-b&b^2\\
c-a-b& c-a-b&(a+b)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$=(a+b+c)^2\begin{vmatrix}
b+c-a &0&a^2\\
0&a+c-b&b^2\\
-2b& -2a& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix} (R_3 \to R_3 -(R_1+R_2))$$

$$=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab}\begin{vmatrix}
a(b+c-a) &0&a^2\\
0&b(a+c-b)&b^2\\
-2ab& -2ab& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

After this just do $R_{1} \to R_1 + R_3$ and $R_{2} \to R_2 + R_3$

$$=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab}\begin{vmatrix}
ab+ac &a^2&a^2\\
b^2&ba+ac&b^2\\
0& 0& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix} ={(a+b+c)^2}\begin{vmatrix}
b+c &a&a\\
b&a+c&b\\
0& 0& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$={(a+b+c)^3}\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a&a\\
1&a+c&b\\
0& 0& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix} = {(a+b+c)^3}\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a&a\\
0&c&b-a\\
0& 0& 2ab\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

This gives the required value of $2abc(a+b+c)^3$.

Comment: Yes, I like this better.

Comment: The device of dividing a by $ab$ is what I wasnt doing. I am wondering if there is a way without this.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I will tell you if I find a way without that.

Comment: Just want to say that having arrived at $\begin{vmatrix} b+c-a&0&a^2\\0&a+c-b&b^2\\-b&-a&ab  \end{vmatrix}$ we see that because of the arrangement of zeros and $a$ and $b$ the determinant is divisible by these and we get $\begin{vmatrix} b+c-a&0&a\\0&a+c-b&b\\-1&-1&1\\ \end{vmatrix}$ Also a bit nonstandard.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the idea of computing the determinant by using its polynomial properties, and symmetry, thus not computing it really. I will try to go in this direction. Let $F(a,b,c)$ be the function given by the determinant from the OP. We know it is a symmetric polynomial of degree $2+2+2=6$ in $a,b,c$.
(And want to show it is $2abc(a+b+c)^3$.)

Let $x$ be some new transcendental variable, and let us compute (generically)
$$
\begin{aligned}
&F(x-b-c,b,c)
\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 &(b+c-x)^2&(b+c-x)^2\\
b^2&(x-b)^2&b^2\\
c^2&c^2&(x-c)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
2bc & 2(b-x)c&2(c-x)b\\
b^2&(b-x)^2&b^2\\
c^2&c^2&(c-x)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
2b^3c^3
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & (1-x/b)&(1-x/c)\\
1&(1-x/b)^2&1\\
1&1&(1-x/c)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
2b^3c^3
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -x/b&-x/c\\
1&-x/b(2-x/b)&0\\
1&0&-x/c(2-x/c)\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
2b^2c^2x^2
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1& 1\\
1& 2-x/b&0\\
1&0& 2-x/c\\
\end{vmatrix}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is a point where i would like to pause.
Now we have some possibilities.

- The first one is further calculating, well, not in the spirit of the OP, but easy to bring to a good end the last determinant. We subtract the first line from the other two. We immediately get $\begin{vmatrix}1-x/b & -1\\-1&1-x/c\end{vmatrix}=(1-x/b)(1-x/c)-1$ and so on.
- But i would like to stop here the calculus, and observe that making $x=0$ in the last determinant we get $\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1& 1\\1 & 2&0\\1&0&2\end{vmatrix}=0$.
  (The sum of the last two rows depends linearly on the first row.) So we can finally isolate the factor $x^3$. So we know that $F(a,b,c)$ of homogeneous degree $6$ has the factors $a,b,c$, and $(a+b+c)^3$. So we need only to determine the constant involved, e.g. from $F(-1,1,1)
  =\begin{vmatrix}4 & 1& 1\\1 & 0&1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix}
  =\begin{vmatrix}2 & 0& 0\\1 & 0&1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix}=-2$.

$\square$

Comment: Well, i this is the most i could do in an elegant direction.